# SOQL Select on FieldPermissions not supported against Developer org

Tags: soql, permissions

Attempting to query FieldPermissions via AJAX (sForce.connection) against a developer org.  The same query via the Developer Console is successful. Also, sforce.connection.query requests against other SObjectTypes such as Account are successful as well as sforce.connection.describeSObject.

Query:

```
sforce.connection.query(SELECT SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'jbbfc__Workorder__c')
```

Result:

```
detail:{InvalidSObjectFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_TYPE', exceptionMessage:'sObject type 'FieldPermissions' is not supported.'
```

Is it that FieldPermissions are retrieved via a method other than 'query'?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What version of the ajax toolkit are you loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing what @ca_peterson said before, check which API version you're using. Support for the FieldPermissions SObject was added in API version 24. If you're using anything prior to that, you'll receive the 'SObject Type Not Supported' error.

I see a lot of javascript snippets out there with `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}` as some of the early examples on here and elsewhere get proliferated via copy/paste.

Comment: The example code we started with was set to version 15.0. Thanks also to @ca_peterson.